# Returned answer wrong in pyschool Topic 2: Q 6

Tags: python

I am trying out the exercises on PySchools and i am stuck on topic:2 Q6.The question is as follows

> Write a function to compute the BMI of a person.
>
> ```
> BMI = weight(kg)  /  ( height(m)*height(m) )
> ```

And i tried this code

```
def BMI(weight, height): 
    return "%.1f"%(weight/(height*height))
```

And i get the results as shown below

[image]

What is the problem here?

Comment: Why are you converting the result to a string?

Comment: First of all i am a newbie i didn't know any other ways to round the decimal points @MartijnPieters

Comment: Are you certain you have to round the result?

Comment: Yeah i guess so because the expected result was 24.2 @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operation

```
weight/(height*height)
```

returns an integer (a whole number). To make the computation as a float, use f.ex.

```
1.0 * weight/(height*height)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: return a string of 1 decimal place.

```
def BMI(weight, height): 
    bmi = float(weight)/(height*height)
    return '%.1f' % bmi
```